# MySQL show all columns while using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Sorry if this is a silly question but did not use much SQL lately and can't find much help on this either.

I need to get all rows to show in a result even if the result is 0 or null. The problem I have is because of the WHERE clause (without the WHERE the rows are all displayed but the data is not).

```
SELECT SUM(c.amount) AS 'total_income', p.ref_id AS 'property'
FROM property p
LEFT JOIN contract c
ON p.id = c.property_ref_id
LEFT JOIN contract_payment cp
ON c.id = cp.contract_id   
WHERE cp.paid = 1 AND year(cp.date_paid) = :year
GROUP BY p.id
```

Displaying the result set without the Where and Bad Data would be like this

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'total_income' => null
      'property' => string 'test/0001' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array
      'total_income' => null
      'property' => string 'test/0002' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array
      'total_income' => string '200' (length=3)
      'property' => string 'test/0003' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array
      'total_income' => string '16100' (length=5)
      'property' => string 'test/0004' (length=9)
```

While this is the result set with the WHERE clause and Good Data but not all rows

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'total_income' => string '4200' (length=4)
      'property' => string 'test/0004' (length=9)
```

Could someone please enlighten me to what modifications could be made to the SQL so as to retrieve my desired data ?

Comment: I think you mean rows, not columns.

Comment: You are right Barmar, Edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're filtering out all the rows with no match in the `cp` table, because `cp.paid` can't be 1 when there's no match there.

Change the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE cp.contract_id IS NULL OR (cp.paid = 1 AND year(cp.date_paid) = :year)
```

or move that condition into the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN with cp:

```
ON c.id = cp.contract_id AND cp.paid = 1 AND year(cp.date_paid) = :year
```

Comment: For some reason the data is still not good but very close. Excellent answer, put me in the right direction. Thanks mate